# Problema ao dar build no projeto em Android

Tags: ionic

Estou tentando dar build em um projeto feito em Ionic para android, mas ele me volta o seguinte erro:

```
cordova build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Projects\primeiro\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Projects\primeiro
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Projects\primeiro\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
**Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2**
```

O Android SDK está instalado, segue uma imagem do mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo entender porque disso acontecer. Eu já instalei os sdk, defini a variável ANDROID_HOME e PATH, e mesmo assim ele continua na mesma mensagem. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela descrição do erro, está faltando o download da API level 22 (Android 5.1.1).

Comment: Cara na hora que li isso dei risada, na moral. Que burro que eu sou, eu estava confundindo Android 2.0 com API level 22, que anta. Agradeço pela resposta. Irei instalar aqui e já dou uma resposta.

Comment: Tudo bem! :D @SCOFIELD

Comment: Pronto. Obrigado novamente.